# How do I redirect to a action outside of the function running the code

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, redirecttoaction

I have a controller that has an Index function that returns a `Task<IActionResult>` and it's connected to a basic Index view. Its URL looks like this `https://localhost:PORT_NUMBER_HERE/CONTROLLER_NAME/Index/1`. As you can see there's also a post id in the URL which determines which post to display in the view. There's another function in the same controller that also returns a `Task<IActionResult>`. Let's call this second function `ProcessData`.

I have a try catch in `ProcessData` that is supposed to redirect back to `https://localhost:PORT_NUMBER_HERE/CONTROLLER_NAME/Index/1` upon a catch. There's a return redirect in the catch like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = dataPlaceholder.Id });
```

but instead it redirects to `https://localhost:PORT_NUMBER_HERE/CONTROLLER_NAME/ProcessData/1`.

I tried changing the catch return to:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "ProcessData", new { id = dataPlaceholder.Id });
```

but it still redirects to `https://localhost:PORT_NUMBER_HERE/CONTROLLER_NAME/ProcessData/1`.

So how do I get the code to redirect to `https://localhost:PORT_NUMBER_HERE/CONTROLLER_NAME/Index/1`?

Comment: does Index action exist in the same controller as the processData ? how does the controller look like ? return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = dataPlaceholder.Id }); should indeed redirect you to https://localhost:PORT_NUMBER_HERE/CONTROLLER_NAME/Index/1

Comment: The `RedirectToAction` should help you to redirect to the Index action method. Per my understanding there must be something wrong within your application. Rebuild and restart the app, client the browser cache and test again. If the issue still exist, could you please try to create a new MVC project then test the Redirect? I just want to make sure the environment is correct. Then I'm afraid we could try to check the routing template/filter middleware/other codes might related. If all of them no luck, could you pls share a minimal sample which could replicate the issue so that we could test?